# servletRequest is a interface or a class?what is the difference between ServletRequest and HttpServletRequest?

Tags: jakarta-ee

basically i want to ask what is the use of HttpServletRequest if we have ServletRequest? if it is use for http protocol then how would our servlet know that the request is httprequest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `ServletRequest` and `HttpServletRequest` are also the interface .

`ServletRequest` represents the most generic concept of a request . It does not know anything about HTTP as it is designed as the protocol independent. `HttpServletRequest` extends it to represent a request that is communicated using a particular protocol which is HTTP in this case.

It is design choice to have these separations such that we can enhance the Servlet container can work with other protocols by simply defining and implementing a new request type that extends `ServletRequest`. Due to the inheritance , we can reusing the existing `ServletRequest` codes and the existing Servlet infrastructure for handling this new protocol.

For example, suppose you invent a protocol (`Sandeep Protocol`) that is superior than HTTP , you can make the servlet container to support it by defining and implement `SandeepServletRequest` which extends `ServletRequest`

> how would our servlet know that the request is httprequest?

It depends on how the protocol is designed. For example, in case of HTTP , the HTTP specification defines the request should looks like:

[image]

So the container may check if the first line of the receiving bytes containing a HTTP method and a word "HTTP" . If yes , it will then regards it as a HTTP request and create a `HttpServletRequest` instance.

Answer (score 1):

ServletRequest provides basic setter and getter methods for requesting a Servlet, but it  doesn't specify how to communicate. HttpServletRequest extends the Interface with getters for HTTP-communication (which is of course the most common way for communicating since Servlets mostly generate HTML).

Servlets can be deployed in a Tomcat-Webserver. Tomcat has a component for handling HTTP-Requests and Responses, called Coyote. So when a request comes in, Coyote creates a HttpServletResponse and HttpServletRequest in which it wraps the Request Parameters. Then it calls the handling method on the Servlet with these two Objects as Parameters, and in this method the Response-Object is modified according to the Request-Object. After that, Coyote creates a HTTP-Response from the HttpServletResponse-Object and sends it back to the requester.

So to answer your question, the servlet knows that the request is a Http-Request because the datatype of the Request-Parameter is HttpServletRequest

Comment: thanks for answering if server sends HttpServletRequest obj then why they call public service method(in which they convert Request into HttpServletRequest and then they call protected Service method.) while they can call protected service method of httpServlet class which have the parameter HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse.@josef98